# Create new array from fragmented array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var res =  ["q:", "Name:David", "Surname:david", "Description:des.", "Title:NewRegister", "fieldtype:phoneTel", "fieldname:(111) 111-1111", "fieldtype:faks", "fieldname:(111) 111-1111", ""]
```

I want to shatter the knee I share. The use of the fieldtype and fieldname that comes with the queue is as follows:

```
fieldtype : fieldname => phoneTel :(111) 111-1111
```

If these names are in them, they will be returned with for and inserted into another array.

```
   var observableArray = ([
            { DataVariable: fieldname[i], DataType: fieldtype[ ?]' },
        ]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djpsmpdm/5/

Comment: in javascript with a 2 sec search `code: var children = hege.concat(stale, kai);`

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more descriptive? for javascript

Comment: here is explained [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_concat) if you dont understand smth comment again what do you want the result to be can you give an example? in your example this would be `code var children = res.concat(observableArray); `